# How should I sort and group data based on different variables

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have data similar to the one below where shows are given a review score.

I have also hot-encoded it with values of either 0 or 1 (true or false) based on their listed genres

| show | review score | Action & Adventure | Anime Features | Anime Series | British TV Shows | Children & Family Movies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| c | 9 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| d | 6 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| e | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| f | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| g | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| h | 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I am trying to group by and sort them based on their values so that it looks something like the below,

With genre coming first, review score in descending order and also count of the number of shows with that review score

| genre | review score | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Action & Adventure | 8 | 2 |
| Anime Features | 10 | 1 |
|  | 9 | 1 |
| Anime Series | 6 | 1 |
| British TV Shows | 9 | 1 |
| Children & Family Movies | 8 | 1 |
|  | 7 | 1 |

I have tried groupby but due to the amount of columns in play, it seems unfeasible.

Comment: Take a look at pd.wide_to_long https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use melt with a groupby.

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['show', 'review score']).groupby(['variable', 'review_score'])['value'].sum()
```

**df1 is:**

```
variable            review score    value
Action & Adventure          6       0
Action & Adventure          7       0
Action & Adventure          8       2
Action & Adventure          9       0
Action & Adventure          10      0
Anime Features              6       0
Anime Features              7       0
Anime Features              8       0
Anime Features              9       1
Anime Features              10      1
Anime Series                6       1
Anime Series                7       0
Anime Series                8       0
Anime Series                9       0
Anime Series                10      0
British TV Shows            6       0
British TV Shows            7       0
British TV Shows            8       0
British TV Shows            9       1
British TV Shows            10      0
Children & Family Movies    6       0
Children & Family Movies    7       1
Children & Family Movies    8       1
Children & Family Movies    9       0
Children & Family Movies    10      0
```

Then filter df1 for counts > 0

```
df1 = df1[df1 > 0]
```

**df1 is:**

```
variable                    review score    value
Action & Adventure          8               2
Anime Features              9               1
Anime Features              10              1
Anime Series                6               1
British TV Shows            9               1
Children & Family Movies    7               1
Children & Family Movies    8               1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grouper = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), axis=1)
out = df.groupby([grouper, df['review score']])['review score'].count()
```

`out`

```
                          review score
Action & Adventure        8               2
Anime Features            9               1
                          10              1
Anime Series              6               1
British TV Shows          9               1
Children & Family Movies  7               1
                          8               1
Name: review score, dtype: int64
```

`out` is series. if you want dataframe, use following code

```
out.rename_axis(['genre', 'review score']).reset_index(name='count')
```

```
    genre                       review score    count
0   Action & Adventure          8               2 
1   Anime Features              9               1
2   Anime Features              10              1
3   Anime Series                6               1
4   British TV Shows            9               1
5   Children & Family Movies    7               1
6   Children & Family Movies    8               1
```